# Authentication with Python, Apache, and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, http-headers, authorization, mod-wsgi

I have been searching vigorously the last week in hopes of finding a solution to my problem. Originally, I had Python configured with CGI on my Windows, Apache, MySQL, and Python server. I understand that CGI is slow and additionally drops **HTTP_AUTHORIZATION** headers before executing the Python environment. I have since configured mod_wsgi and added the following to my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /flex/entry "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/flex/entry.wsgi"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

My understanding is that **HTTP_AUTHORIZATION** would normally now be accessible in Python via `os.environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`. However, this is not the case.

Can someone please explain what I am missing/doing wrong?

Thanks!
Trent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's passed in the mapping passed as `environ` to the main WSGI function.

Comment: thanks! the few examples i could find suggested using os.environ.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION") which clearly is out of the scope.